# Failing to install craco

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

```
npm ERR! While resolving: frontend@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react-scripts@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"^5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react-scripts@"^5.0.0" from craco-esbuild@0.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/craco-esbuild
npm ERR!     dev craco-esbuild@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-scripts@"^4.0.0" from @craco/craco@6.4.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@craco/craco
npm ERR!   dev @craco/craco@"6.4.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @craco/craco@"^6.0.0" from craco-esbuild@0.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/craco-esbuild
npm ERR!     dev craco-esbuild@"*" from the root project
```

i dont get it
i already have the dependency
5.0.0 in my project
craco wants 4.0.0
but its saying it failed

Comment: That's unfortunate, but it appears that **craco 6.4.3** published 2 months ago is not compatible with **react-scripts 5.0.0** published at about the same time. Caret (`^`) dependency does not allow for major version change: [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004). You can try risking it with [version 7 alpha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco/v/7.0.0-alpha.0)

Comment: @tromgy I think i'll try vite instead

Answer (score 1):

The issue is a result of CRA 5 update - meaning that you're using react version 5.0.0 vs Craco requires react 4.0.0.

The Craco team is working on this issue - You may check this for further details

Craco Github: https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/issues/378

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

```
"@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
"craco-less": "^2.1.0-alpha.0"
"react-scripts": "5.0.1"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).